# redis php and javascript connection

Tags: javascript, php, redis

I am making a web chat client where I use redis for pub/sub. I am having trouble with the subscribe part. I am able to publish but I am not sure how to subscribe. I have a php script written to subscribe (it work when I run php) it listens and echos the message. I want to be able to get that message in javascript. How do I call the php file and listen? I tried ajax in jquery and listening for the echo in the success function but it does not seem to work. I am new to this any advice is helpful

EDIT: Here is the javascript

```
$.ajax({
url:"http://localhost/redisphp.php",
type: GET,
success: function(response){ ...},
...
```

Here is the redis. I modeled after this link https://xmeng.wordpress.com/2011/11/14/pubsub-in-redis-using-php/

```
<?php
function f($redis, $chan, $msg) {
switch($chan) {
    case 'chan-1':
        echo $msg;
}
}

ini_set('default_socket_timeout', -1);

$redis = new Redis();
$redis->pconnect('128.0.0.0',6378);

$redis->subscribe(array('chan-1'), 'f');
print "\n";

?>
```

Comment: perhaps you can show us what you wrote?

Comment: I showed how I call the php and the php file itself

Comment: Have you looked at the browser console for javascript errors ?

Comment: ypu nothing wrong there

Comment: What about doing `console.log(response);` in the `success` clause ? Also, could you show the full javascript ?

Comment: It does not hit the success function. I presume because it has persistent connection?

Comment: Do you mean the php file never stops executing ? Are you not running into `max_execution_time` ? Is that script actually supposed to run on a server or in the command line ?

Answer (score 0):

I have a php script written to subscribe (it work when I run php) it listens and echos the message. I want to be able to get that message in javascript.

It sounds like you would need to create an Express API that would connect to your Redis server.

Please keep in mind I am going on very limited information that you have provided. So first thing with your Express API is to create your `package.json` file like so:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "4.16.3",
    "redis": "2.8.0",
    "nodemon": "1.18.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon",
    "start": "node index.js"
  }
}
```

You don't want it to look exactly like this of course, but just pointing you in the right of what you want to be doing. Of course you will need to do an `npm install` for those particular dependencies.

Then if I were you I would create a `server/keys.js` file like so:

```
module.exports = {
  redisHost: process.env.REDIS_HOST,
  redisPort: process.env.REDIS_PORT,
};
```

And then require that inside a `server/index.js` file where you will also add the following:

```
const keys = require("./keys");

// Express App Setup
const express = require("express");

const app = express();

// Redis Client Setup
const redis = require(‘redis’);
const redisClient = redis.createClient({
    host: keys.redisHost,
    port: keys.redisPort,
    retry_strategy: () => 1000
});
const redisPublisher = redisClient.duplicate();
```

So this `retry_strategy` takes an arrow function and it is saying that if we ever lose connection to the redis server try to reconnect to it once every second.

The key for `retry_strategy` is separated by an underscore as opposed to the JavaScript standard of camelCase.

According to the Redis documentation for the Javascript library, if we ever have a client that is listening or publishing information on Redis we have to make a duplicate connection between when a connection is turned into one that is going to listen, subscribe or publish information, it cannot be used for other purposes.

So thats why I am doing this `duplicate()` thing at the end of `redisClient`.

So that is pretty much it.